# Calculate total amount deliveries

Tags: python, python-3.x

For you to solve my problem I think you have to run it on your own. My problem is in this line   `print(Customer_Name, "has spent", Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'], "in total")`

[image: Output]

For you to understand better. For example here, It says `Michael has spent 60.0 in total` when it should be `Michael has spent 20.0 in total`

```
 import datetime
 import uuid  # GET A RANDOM ID FOR THE CUSTOMER
 from csv import DictWriter
 from datetime import date  # GET CURRENT DATE AND TOMORROW DATE
 import os


def openFile():  # STARTS HERE
    try:
        os.startfile('data_entered.csv')

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        # OPEN FILE WHEN USER(EMPLOYEE) WANTS TO


def closeFile():
    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe')

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))  # ENDS HERE


file = open('CustomerNames.txt', 'a')
file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'a')
file2 = open('data_entered.csv', 'a')

ORDERS_FROM_EMPLOYEE = 0
x = -1
length = 0
Total_Amount = 0.0
Customer_List = []
Address_List = []
My_List = []
today = datetime.date.today()
Today_Key = date.toordinal(date.today())
Today_Date = date.today()
Tomorrow_Date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
Customers = {}
Dates = {}

print("Welcome to our coffee shop!")
print("Login")

# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS STARTS
UserLogin = {"Employee1": "coffeeshop1", "Employee2": "coffeeshop2", "Employee3": "coffeeshop3"}
username = password = ''
while True:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    if (username in UserLogin) and (UserLogin[username] == password):
        print("Login Successful")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Login. Try again")
# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS ENDS

# PROCESS AFTER ORDER PLACEMENT STARTS
print("Current Date is: {}".format(Today_Date))
process1 = True
process2 = True
while process1:
    while process2:
        x += 1

        Customer_Name = input("Customer's Name:")
        Customer_Address = input("Customer's Address:")

        if Customer_Name in Customer_List and Customer_Address in Address_List:
            First_Index = Customer_List.index(Customer_Name)
            Second_Index = Address_List.index(Customer_Address)
            if Customer_Name == Customer_List[First_Index]:
                Customer_List.pop(First_Index)
                x -= 1

        Address_List.append(Customer_Address)
        Customer_List.append(Customer_Name)

        if Today_Key not in Dates:
            Dates[Today_Key] = {}
            if Customer_Name not in Dates[Today_Key]:
                Dates[Today_Key][Customer_Name] = 1
            else:
                Dates[Today_Key][Customer_Name] += 1

        if Customer_Name in Customers:
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] += 1
            Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount
        else:
            Customers[Customer_Name] = {}
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Name'] = Customer_Name
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Address'] = Customer_Address
            Customers[Customer_Name]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] = 1
            Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = 0

        Order_Price = float(input("Total amount of order:"))
        ORDERS_FROM_EMPLOYEE += 1

        print(Customer_Name, "has ordered {} time(s)".format(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']))

        Total_Amount = Order_Price + Total_Amount

        if Tomorrow_Date == Today_Date:  # WHEN THIS IS TRUE, IT MEANS THAT THE DATE CHANGED
            print("Total amount of orders today is:{} ".format(Total_Amount))  # NUMBER OF ORDERS IN ONE SPECIFIC DAY
        answer1 = input("Send another order? (Y/N)").lower()

        if Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] == 1:
            print("This is the first time", Customer_Name, "orders")
            Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Order_Price
        else:  # TOTAL AMOUNT OF ALL ORDERS DELIVERED
            print(Customer_Name, "has spent", Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'], "in total")

        process2 = answer1 == "y"

    LengthCustomersList = len(Customer_List)
    length += 1

    if int(length) == int(LengthCustomersList):
        process1 = False

file1.write(username + " has placed {} orders today".format(ORDERS_FROM_EMPLOYEE))

for i in Customer_List:
    file.write(i + '\n')

csv_writer = DictWriter(open('data_entered.csv', 'a'),
                        fieldnames=['Customer Name', 'Customer Address', 'Customer ID', 'Total Orders',
                                    'Total Amount'])

csv_writer.writeheader()

for customer_name in Customers.keys():
    csv_writer.writerows(
        [{'Customer Name': Customers[customer_name]['Name'],
          'Customer Address': Customers[customer_name]['Address'],
          'Customer ID': Customers[customer_name]['ID'],
          'Total Orders': Customers[customer_name]['Orders'],
          'Total Amount': Customers[customer_name]['TotalAmount']}])

openFile()

file.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

I have tried adding a `Customers[Customer_Name]['Order_Price']` but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the `Total_Amount` variable. Its value is kept from the last iteration and assigned to the next customer. You need to retrieve it from your `Customers` dictionary and then update the value in the dictionary after.

```
if Customer_Name in Customers:
    Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] += 1
    # Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount  # This is where the error was
else:
    Customers[Customer_Name] = {}
    Customers[Customer_Name]['Name'] = Customer_Name
    Customers[Customer_Name]['Address'] = Customer_Address
    Customers[Customer_Name]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
    Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] = 1
    Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = 0

Total_Amount = Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount']  # retrieve value here

Order_Price = float(input("Total amount of order:"))
ORDERS_FROM_EMPLOYEE += 1

print(Customer_Name, "has ordered {} time(s)".format(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']))

Total_Amount = Order_Price + Total_Amount
Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount  # update value here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understood what I did wrong.